# jQuery - swap images and text at regular intervals

Tags: javascript, jquery, animate.css

I have two images and their corresponding text in two columns. Right now, I have one picture fade in down and the text fade in up at the same time. I want the text to fade out up and picture to fade out down, every four seconds and have the other picture and text fade in automatically. How to achieve this animation? I suspect I might need to add in a data structure, probably a queue (because of the way it will enter and exit).

The animations used are from animate.css

HTML:

```
    <div class="group">
       <div class="left">
          <img src="images/the_principal.jpg" alt="school principal" class="admin-pic">
          <!--<img src="images/mrs-cooke.png" alt="school vice principal" class="admin-pic">-->
       </div>
       <div class="right">
           <p class="text">
            "Education is a simple yet a serious process. It is a process of making a human being into 'being human'.Stress at our institution is on this aspect.<br>I invite you to join us and make our country proud
                            <br><br>-The Principal"
           </p>

           <!--<p>
                        "We are all Indians firstly and lastly. Whatever anyone else might say, we need to uphold this God-given identity
                        through our actions, thoughts and what we might say.<br>Long live the Indian Republic.
                        <br><br>-The Vice Principal "
           </p>-->
       </div>
   </div>
```

The second picture and text is commented out.

jQuery:

```
var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';

$('.offscreen-logo').addClass('come-in-logo').one(animationEnd,function(){
      $('.right .text').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
      $('.left .admin-pic').addClass('animated fadeInDown');
 });
```

Comment: Have you tried using an `array` and a `setInterval`?

Comment: yes, but it wasn't getting up the animations, and the images weren't coming up at all

Comment: You have to post a working fiddle for anybody to look it up for you. Currently what you want is very vague.